# Need progressively harder isolation core & abs exercises

Tags: exercise, abdominals, core

For context, I can do about 40 strict form crunches, 12-13 pullups, 30+ pushups. I've seen a little improvement in definition but not a lot.

I have a resistance band and pullup bar that I could use.

What are some other progressively harder isolation exercises I could do to strengthen my core?

Comment: Just as an FYI, core muscles are way more than just the abdominals. There are quite a few more than just the rectus abdominus

Comment: Are you only looking to improve your abs, or your entire core?

Answer (score 4):

There's two separate issues here: definition and strength.

Definition is primarily diet.

Searching the web for ab/core exercises provides a wealth of options. Without equipment:

- Strict crunches
- Crunch variations (heel taps, bicycle crunches, etc.)
- Planks (and their variations, moving and static)
- Mountain climbers
- Hollow holds
- Flutter kicks (and leg lifts etc., mind the back though)
- Bird dogs
- Dead bugs

There's dozens of options. With equipment, cable crunches, which can also be done banded.

Answer (score 0):

Just body weight will do. Try this:

1. Lie down on your back. Legs straight
2. Make sure your back is neutral
3. While keeping your legs on the ground, curl yourself up (trying to bring your chest to your legs)
4. Do not use momentum to curl up. Curl up for say 10-15 degrees, pause, and then continue. This is done to remove the momentum due to the weight of your head
5. As you are curling to 45-60 degrees, think of posteriorly tilting your pelvis, to engage your lower abs to help you
6. If doing right, 4-5 reps should burn you out